# Strimzi Kafka "brokers without a matching listener" during GKE Upgrade

Tags: apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, broker, strimzi

I deployed Kafka using the strimzi operator version 0.15 on GKE and is working fine. The config is this:

```
  kafka:
    version: 2.3.1
    replicas: 3
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      log.message.format.version: "2.3"
```

When I did an upgrade of the kubernetes cluster, obviously also each Kafka Pod has been restarted, and during the upgrade I saw many of the following messages in the logs coming from clients trying to communicate with Kafka:

> xxx Partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener,
> including....

and

> Connection to node 1 (kafka-1.redacted.svc.cluster.local/redacted:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

So, I wonder if this is a normal behavior or if this isn't supposed to happen.
After the GKE Upgrade everything was working fine without any problem.

During the upgrade also the kafka-exporter (gets deployed together with the strimzi operator) was logging:

> In the middle of a leadership election, there is currently no leader for this partition and hence it is unavailable for writes

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your Kafka config does not have / show any listeners configuration. Without that it is not a valid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i guess I found the problem, some clients created topics with replication 1, this would answer the questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).